# Get access to specific spreadsheet by GData library or get work libraries from NuGet in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-api, nuget, monodevelop

I'm writing test program, all done exept saving data in spreadsheet. I want use Google Docs, but, because i use Unity - i can't use Google.Apis libraries - they use NuGet to be installed and if Monodevelop recognize them,  Unity dont see them. So i have only GData libraries.

In other words i can do:

```
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Spreadsheets;
```

But i can't:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
```

If i'll use OAuth identefications I'll get access to user's Drive. How i can get access to my own drive, no mater, on what PC program is running?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Just use NuGet to install all the libraries and its dependencies in MonoDevelop, and then manually copy the libraries from the NuGet installation folder to a folder inside your unity project. Unity will recognize them and will be available from MonoDevelop.

You should be able to install the libraries manually without using NuGet though.

Keep in mind that Unity ships with a .NET version equivalent to .NET 3.5 so only libraries with .NET 3.5 support will work. (thanks Venkat)

Comment: Only applies if the packages support .Net 3.5 though. Mono for Unity still doesn't support anything further than 3.5

Comment: I've tryed this, Unity give me Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded, so thx for answer, but it is not work this way.

Comment: Yup, basically that means that the package uses something that doesn't exist in .Net 3.5